# How to save the link of the file uploaded in the database and the actual file in a specific folder in django

Tags: django, filefield

I have a form with an upload option (filefeild). The file uploaded is saved directly in the databse. I need to store the file in a specific folder and the link to the file on the database

For now the uploaded file is directly stored in the database table

```py
def uploaddata(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = dataform(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('file_list')
        else:
                form = dataform()
        return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {
                'form': form
        })
```

This is my model

```py
class Metadataform(models.Model):

    Type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Vars = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    Error = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    Document = models.FileField(upload_to="store/Data/")
```

And also i want the files to be stored outside the media folder somewhere on the server in a given path. could you help me define the Media path

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = '../store/Data/'
MEDIA_URL = 'store/Data/'
```

Comment: django already does what you want. If you want to save files somewhere in the server then just put `MEDIA_ROOT='/path/to/server/folder'`

Comment: How do i add the link to that file on the database?

Comment: its already added. you can get it via `Metadataform.objects.first().Document.url`

Comment: Could you please be more specific. I am completely new to django. 1.What do i specify in the models.FileField(upload_to= ....)

Comment: Please read this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: If you run your function and then look in the database, you'll see the location of the file has been stored (assuming your function is working).

Comment: Thank you. The file is getting uploaded and i can just see the name of the file in the database. The file is not in the media directory, i do not know where the file is being stored. How do i check?